# missing ADO connection functionality when running old vb6 app on win 2016

Tags: vb6, migration, windows-server-2016

*THIS HAS BEEN EDITED, SEE BOTTOM. I CHANGED THE TITLE TO BETTER REFLECT THE PROBLEM.**

I have an old vb6 application that I put on a windows 2016 server and been having issues with dependency files. I ran process monitor and started putting the dll files in the locations where it is looking at, most of them have cleared up.

I'm getting one that I cant find on the old win 2000 box or anywhere else: `wow64log.dll`

Where can I can get this file? I attached pics of proc mon and the list of dependencies that the app is requiring. any direction would be appreciated. third pic is the actual error when trying to open the app. *edit* added the dependency walker screen shot

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

EDIT*** 
so I have narrowed down the issue and it boils down to an ADO connection. I cant seem to connect on windows server 2016 using ADO. I suspect it has something to do with the connection string, but what baffles me is why does this work on a win 10,1803 box and not on windows server 2016 1607 ?

this is basically my issue - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/f1eee40b-6ab2-445f-a361-ae965439273a/run-time-error-214746725980004005-for-using-adodbconnection?forum=isvvba

[image]

Comment: Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) could be useful.
Just open WinderToCognex.exe with DW.

Comment: The references window only shows DLLs which support COM interfaces. Not all DLLs do and it looks like WOW64LOG may not be.

Comment: @Smith, I rand dependency walker and from the way it looks am I correct to suspect that NTDLL.DLL is the source issue? ignore the circled MSVBVM60.dll in the pic.

Comment: read this after looking at where I can get the DLL but seems I may not need it. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/missing-api-ms-win-core-dlls/d99d1368-0f92-43db-bbdb-7d080f1f96e9

Comment: Is your program actually having a problem at runtime? If so, what is it?

Comment: it throws that automation error, from googling the error code I see references to MDAC which uses it OLE and ODBC connect and links the old legacy OS' but win 2016 server doesn't need that from my understanding . https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/run-time-error-91-21470247024769-8007007f-is-it-mdac-problem.489410/

Comment: If that automation error pops up while running in VB6 IDE, try with Ctrl+Pause(Break) instead of clicking OK button. If not, try to estimate which procedure (must be some without an error handler) throws that exception and add some error handling code.

Comment: I don't even know if Windows Server 2016 supports it, but did you (try to) install the VB6 runtime on it?

Comment: I did put some error catching in there and basically it bombs because it is trying to make an ADO connection object but cannot. it works on a win 10 1803 box perfectly but not on this server. and from what I hear win 2016 does support vb6 apps. so im missing something here. I installed so many different KB files and patches that one included, to try to get it to work and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is not an actual error in the runtime of your program, If you are only looking at Procmon, be aware that it shows a lot of stuff and sometimes not all the "errors" there are really relevant. For instance, it will often show how Windows functions look in a long list of search paths, each failing in turn, before that actual location of a DLL is detected.

In this case, it seems most likely that a missing `wow64log.dll` is harmless and apparently, totally normal.

"WoW64" is the Windows subsystem which runs 32 bit programs inside the 64 bit operating system. ("WoW" stands for "Windows-on-Windows".)

According to the reference [WoW64 Internals](https://wbenny.github.io/2018/11/04/wow64-internals.html) describing how this subsystem is initialized:

> ### wow64!ProcessInit
>
> ...
>
> It … tries to load the *wow64log.dll* from the constructed system
>   directory. **Note that this DLL is never present in any released
>   Windows installation** (it’s probably used internally by Microsoft for
>   debugging of the WoW64 subsystem). Therefore, *load of this DLL will
>   normally fail*. This isn’t problem, though, because no critical
>   functionality of the WoW64 subsystem depends on it.

Although that article is talking about the ARM64 architecture (which AFAIK is not what most PCs would be using) it sounds like much of the WoW64 system is similar to normal PCs.

Comment: I edited post and posted a pic of the error when opening the app it may be something different unrelated to that dll as well.